# @EntityListeners equivalent for @ElementCollection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitylisteners

I've a very simple problem which I would like a simple solution but it seems there isn't a default approach on JPA/Hibernate

I've an BasicEntity which has a Listener to monitor persists and updates

My entity has a

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JsonProperty("images")
   @Column(length = 256)
   private final List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();
```

Everything works fine, the listener is being called on updates and creation, the problem is whenever I alter the images, the entity listener isn't called

the data is correctly stored in the database, but JPA doesn't invoke the update hooks for the listener.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider this a bug if a `@PreUpdate` listener is not called when you change just the images list. You should [report that on JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net) and attach a [reproducing test case](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java).

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are aware of that... I've found many people complaining the same problem... not sure what was the design goal, but preupdate is only called if the repository.save() will update the table.... and in the case i related the update will be done in another table

Comment: According to the JPA spec 3.5.3: `The PreUpdate and PostUpdate callbacks occur before and after the database update operations to entity data respectively`. The specification unfortunately misses to define what "entity data" means exactly, but I would argue that `@ElementCollection` and `@Embedded` are subsumed under that term. I am a Hibernate developer and I didn't know about this issue, so please report that problem with a test case :)